# C# User Control (with sequences). Navigate within WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2015

I'm looking for the best, most effecient way of implimenting user controls navigation based on events, below is the intended use.

I also don't know what is best, to have the next back button on the control or form.

Lastly, the next button may sometimes change and initially be validate on some controls and then if validated change to next if the validate is ok.

Ok the concept:

I have 1 primary user control with 3 checkboxes, behind each checkbox is a sequence of more user forms therefore, if all three are selected it should then load all three sequences one after another.

Regardless of how many are selected, all sequences end with the same final user control.

Basically I need to understand the best and most practicle way approach this (examples welcome).

There are lots of topics that cover winforms / user control navigation but I cannot seem to see a solution which pops out to me and fits my needs.

For compatibility with some systems, I have decided to use .net 3.5; should this make a difference in suggestions.

Feedback, links, code etc all welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar scenario some years ago. If memory serves, I approached it as follows:

1. Separate the navigation buttons into their own control that groups
   the buttons together. Design this control to support docking.
2. In this control, provide distinct buttons for Back, Next, Finish and
   Cancel. Provide separate properties on the control that determine
   what the user can do: CanMoveBack, CanMoveForward, CanFinish, and
   CanCancel. The container should be able to set these.
3. In the setter for the navigation properties, you want to be able to
   adjust the visibility/disabled status of each of the navigation
   buttons. Don't hot-swap text. That way, each button does one thing,
   and only one thing. This keeps their event handlers nice and clean.
4. The user control itself should raise events: OnBackClicked,
   OnNextClicked, OnFinishClicked, and OnCancelClicked. Your button
   event handlers should raise these. The container should decide what
   to do when they are clicked.

Comment: Excellent thanks, this seems like an approach I can follow. I just need to redesign my controls to add the buttons now ;)